# Multiple boxes with Azure provider

Tags: azure, vagrant

I'm using [Azure provider for Vagrant](https://github.com/Azure/vagrant-azure) and trying to create 2 identical VM's.

```
Vagrant.configure('2') do |config|
  v1 = 2
  config.vm.box = 'azure'

  v1.times do |i|
    config.vm.provider :azure do |azure, override|  
      azure.resource_group_name = "random-#{i}"
    end
  end
end
```

This does create a VM in Azure, but only one. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you have a loop with the `.times` method you still create a single VM, you need to create each VM each time you iterate in the loop. A new machine is created using the `config.vm.define` method call (see [vagrant multi machine doc](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/multi-machine/))

```
Vagrant.configure('2') do |config|
  v1 = 2
  config.vm.box = 'azure'

  v1.times do |i|
    config.vm.define "random-#{i}" do |node|
      node.vm.provider :azure do |azure, override|  
        azure.resource_group_name = "random-#{i}"
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: sorry did not include the link - you can check the vagrant doc on multi machine https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/multi-machine/

Comment: and what would be a good read about vagrantfile structure? say, I had no idea I had to define a vm.

Comment: its a trick question ! I would start with the [general doc](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/vagrantfile/) there are tons of blog post about vagrant usage but I find many gets outdated so check when they were posted

Comment: thanks, I guess I'll look for your help a little bit more in a couple of following days :)